# macOS Monterey: Bluetooth mic issues when Mute/Adjust input volume

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

Whenever I try to mute my Bluetooth audio input (mic) by either applying a shortcut with the following code `set volume input volume 0` or by manually minimizing the sound to 0 on `Sound Preferences -> Input`, I receive unwanted behavior:
All my audio (both input and output) is muted, then if I modify the output audio, I got immediately unmuted.

Also, from the additional observations:

1. This only happens when I got both Input and Output set to my Bluetooth headphones and mic
2. Mute works fine when applied to the `MacBook Pro Microphone` input source
3. When I navigate to `Sound Preferences -> Input`, while listening to music, the audio quality degrades dramatically.
4. It all started happening after I upgraded to `macOS Monterey` and worked completely okay in `macOS Big Sur`

Could you please advice of how this issue can be resolved?

Thank you!

`UPD` as of 12/14/2021

The issue persists in the Monterey 12.1.

`UPD` as of 02/01/2022

Still not fixed in 12.2

`UPD` as of 03/01/2022

Still not fixed in 12.2.1

`UPD` as of 03/15/2022

Still not fixed in 12.3

Comment: Still not fixed in 12.3.1

Comment: i read on reddit that disabling "airplay receiver" in preferences → sharing solves this? can anyone confirm/refute this?

Answer (score 7):

There’s a bug in macOS Monterey when using Bluetooth headphones. Any time a Bluetooth headset’s mic is muted, the output is muted as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not really a source but the FAQ for the app Mic Drop has a mention of this bug, saying it was reported to Apple. https://getmicdrop.com/help/

Comment: My temporary workaround to this bug is to mute then quickly volume up with my external keyboard button to bring back the audio output.

Comment: I got another workaround. I have a tool that controls muting _only_ non-bluetooth devices. I got the hint from this page https://retina.studio/ears/monterey-mute/

Answer (score 3):

It appears to have been fixed with macOS Monterey 12.4 I have just updated to.

Steps to verify:

1. Connect bluetooth headphones.
2. Follow Sound Preferences -> Sound -> Input.
3. Play some music.
4. Drag the input volume slider all the way to the left.

The sound should not be muted when dragging the input slider to 0.

Comment: I can confirm it's finally fixed on 12.4 

Comment: Same here my app that mutes (not just volume zero) the Bluetooth microphone do not mute my sound outputs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

i ended up just saving the current output Volume in a variable before setting input to 0, then reset output to the original value.

tested in phone calls and while listening to music, the output volume switch to 0 and back up so quick that it is not noticable (least for me)

Sample code on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/cy4n/raycast-microphone-toggle/-/commit/c62233790ada64970f598d42975b7ec47192f35b) and below.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

# Required parameters:
# @raycast.schemaVersion 1
# @raycast.title muteme
# @raycast.mode silent

# Optional parameters:
# @raycast.icon 

# Documentation:
# @raycast.author cy


on getMicrophoneVolume()
    input volume of (get volume settings)
end getMicrophoneVolume

on getOutputVolume()
    output volume of (get volume settings)
end getOutputVolume

if getMicrophoneVolume() is greater than 0 then
    # remember outputVolume original value
    local outputVolume
    set outputVolume to getOutputVolume()
    
    # set input volume to 0, (mute)
    set volume input volume 0

    # set output volume back to original value (in MacOS Monterey this gets set to 0 when input Volume is being set to 0)
    set volume output volume outputVolume 
    
    
    say "muted" using "Samantha"
    display notification "Microphone Muted"
else
    set volume input volume 100
    say "unmuted" using "Samantha"
    display notification "Microphone Activated"
end if
```

Comment: Hi, simply using this sequence may work in your "muting" code part :
"set volume input volume 0" then  
"set volume without output muted"

Answer (score 0):

I use a third party app to mute my mic. When the mic is muted, the audio drops on my AirPods as well. This issue only started after I updated to macOS Monterey. Hopefully someone found a fix or Apple fixes this with an update - this is clearly a bug and I have it too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a bug in macOS Monterey.

**Here are the steps to reproduce:**

1. Connect any bluetooth headset to the computer.
2. Open the "audio MIDI setup" application which is a default macOS
   application.
3. Find the headset you connected via bluetooth and find it on the input pane it might show up as two separate devices.
4. Play any audio source (maybe play clip from youtube).
5. Go back to the "audio MIDI setup" application and click/check the mute checkbox next to the slider on the input pane.
6. At this point the **output** will be muted; what should happen (desired behavior) is the **input** should be muted but it should not impact the output.

This is not the desired behavior.

Hopefully someone at Apple can fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Working as of 06/06.
macOC Monterey 12.4.
Try [MuteKey](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/mutekey/id1509590766?mt=12)!

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed for me in MacOS 12.4